# How can I convert an existing image field into a Media image reference field?

Tags: 8, media

I have an image field that I created before Drupal 8.5, when media was introduced in the ui. The field already contains content and I would like to make use of the reusable media functionality that is now in core. How can I make use of media for this image field without deleting the current content and having to create a new media field?

Comment: https://chromatichq.com/blog/migrating-drupal-file-fields-media-entities-without-migrate-module this should do it.

Comment: Actually it works! https://chromatichq.com/blog/migrating-drupal-file-fields-media-entities-without-migrate-module